# How to generate source code of secure wsdl url

Tags: soap, wsimport

I want to generate source code and java file of that url.

I am trying like below code.

This is content of my authFile.txt file which is at /data/soap/

http://username:password$@hostname/path?WSDL

And my wsimport command is

```
wsimport -keep -d soap -verbose -Xnocompile -Xauthfile /data/soap/authFile.txt  http://xyz.xyz.com:50000/dir/wsdl?p=ic/d67b8fdfbf3556621189144a749fd10e680
```

but getting error as below:

> Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection timed out
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document: http://xyz.xyz.com:50000/dir/wsdl?p=ic/d67b8fdfbf3556621189144a749fd10e680, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not `<wsdl:definitions>`.
>
> [ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
>
> Failed to parse the WSDL.